# Definition of random measure (studying Lévy processes)

Tags: measure-theory, definition, stochastic-calculus, random, levy-processes

While studying Lévy processes and Poisson processes, I have encountered the jump random measure
$$\mu^{X}(\omega, \cdot)=\sum_{t \geq 0} \delta_{\left(t, \Delta X_{t}(\omega)\right)} .$$
My confusion lies within the definition of random measure, since many textbooks introduce a **random measure** differently.

*Kallenberg (Probability and its Applications)* introduces it as

> By a random measure on $S$ we mean a
> ($\sigma$-finite) kernel  from the basic probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ into $\mathcal S$.

With (transition) kernel we mean as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel, so we want it to be a measure when fixing $\omega\in\Omega$, and want it to be a random variable when fixing a Borel set $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R\backslash \{0\}).$

> > However, in *Appelbaum (Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus)* on p. 103, it defines a random measure without the assumption it is a measure when fixing $\omega$. And, on the other hand, in *Jacod and Shiryaev (Limit theorems for stochastic processes)* on p. 65, a random measure is a family of random measure, but they do not state the condition we want it to be a random variable when fixing $A$.

Any comments that would resolve my confusion? I am trying to understand why $\mu^X$ is well-defined.